# Target a value of an array within another array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json file that has arrays within an array and for the life of me I can't think of how to access a particular value from the inner array when using ng-repeat.

So here is a sample of the json file I'm using:

```
{
  "data" : [ [ 1, "F32A106E-76E3-49E5-AF73-22690DFA892B", 1, 1470051383, "939314", 1470051383, "939314", null, "122151194", "12 STONE CONTRACTING GROUP, INC.", "FOREIGN BUSINESS CORPORATION", "2016-06-01T00:00:00", "MAILING ADDRESS", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "PO BOX 8958", null, "ATLANTA", "GA", "31106" ]
, [ 2, "96752850-352F-4D9F-B1C0-80BE194C8B6B", 2, 1470051383, "939314", 1470051383, "939314", null, "122151194", "12 STONE CONTRACTING GROUP, INC.", "FOREIGN BUSINESS CORPORATION", "2016-06-01T00:00:00", "PRINCIPAL PLACE OF BUSINESS", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "5855 HIGHWAY 5", null, "DOUGLASVILLE", "GA", "30135" ]
, [ 3, "CE0A65F3-01D2-4F07-A2EE-8EC22091D9EA", 3, 1470051383, "939314", 1470051383, "939314", null, "122151194", "12 STONE CONTRACTING GROUP, INC.", "FOREIGN BUSINESS CORPORATION", "2016-06-01T00:00:00", "REGISTERED AGENT", null, null, null, null, null, "329227", "C T CORPORATION SYSTEM", "388 STATE ST STE 420", null, "SALEM", "OR", "97301" ]
, [ 4, "050AD941-5A5B-4068-917D-0025763A3E9F", 4, 1470051383, "939314", 1470051383, "939314", null, "122141294", "ABBA'S GARDEN", "DOMESTIC NONPROFIT CORPORATION", "2016-06-01T00:00:00", "MAILING ADDRESS", "KYLE", null, "ROY", null, null, null, null, "2426 SE 70TH AVE", null, "PORTLAND", "OR", "97206" ]
, [ 5, "6784F41D-C101-4630-BC1A-86EEDA054D1C", 5, 1470051383, "939314", 1470051383, "939314", null, "122141294", "ABBA'S GARDEN", "DOMESTIC NONPROFIT CORPORATION", "2016-06-01T00:00:00", "REGISTERED AGENT", "KYLE", null, "ROY", null, null, null, null, "2426 SE 70TH AVE", null, "PORTLAND", "OR", "97206" ]
, [ 6, "216D4AF9-7917-473A-9E9F-45B4DF6D0695", 6, 1470051383, "939314", 1470051383, "939314", null, "122140098", "AIR 1 PLUMBING INC", "FOREIGN BUSINESS CORPORATION", "2016-06-01T00:00:00", "MAILING ADDRESS", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "9012 NE 89TH CIRCLE", null, "VANCOUVER", "WA", "98662" ]
, [ 7, "5AB2BC67-C612-459A-B3CE-0C454413522F", 7, 1470051383, "939314", 1470051383, "939314", null, "122140098", "AIR 1 PLUMBING INC", "FOREIGN BUSINESS CORPORATION", "2016-06-01T00:00:00", "PRINCIPAL PLACE OF BUSINESS", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "9012 NE 89TH CIRCLE", null, "VANCOUVER", "WA", "98662" ]
, [ 11497, "35C994F6-51B3-4731-ABA0-0B081E291D84", 11497, 1470051406, "939314", 1470051406, "939314", null, "122972292", "PNW ROOFING LLC", "DOMESTIC LIMITED LIABILITY COMPANY", "2016-06-30T00:00:00", "REGISTERED AGENT", "ANATOLIY", null, "KHARKOV", null, null, null, null, "1334 MCGEE CT NE APT 204", null, "KEIZER", "OR", "97303" ]
 ]
}
```

My thought was to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in results">{{x.data[6]}}</div>
```

But the above just gives me all the values in line 7 and not what I'm really looking for, which is a list of all the 7th place values in each of the inner arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in results">
    <div ng-repeat="y in x">y[6]</div>
</div>
```